# Inconsistent error due to no time.sleep?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I wrote for practice purposes a little Python script in which I calculate all primes to a given value. But I experience some inconsistent errors.

At first here's the code:

```
import datetime
import time
import threading
class myThread (threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, threadID, name, threadcounter):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.threadID = threadID
    self.name = name
    self.threadcounter = threadcounter
  def run(self):
    delete_non_primes (self.threadcounter)
print ('This script outputs all primes until the given value. \nWhat value shall be calculated until? ')
maxval = int(input("Please enter the wanted value: "))
print ('Preparing...')
primes = []
primes.append(0)
primes.append(0)
primes.append(2)
i = 3
for i in range (3,maxval+1):
  primes.append(i)
if primes[3]!=3:
  import sys
  sys.exit("An error occured.")
counter = 1
percent = 0
thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1 iniated", 0)
thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2 iniated", 0)
thread3 = myThread(3, "Thread-3 iniated", 0)
thread4 = myThread(4, "Thread-4 iniated", 0)
thread5 = myThread(5, "Thread-5 iniated", 0)
nr_of_threads = 0
def delete_non_primes ( prime ):
  if prime != 0:
    breaker = prime
    while (breaker < maxval):
      breaker = breaker +1
      if primes[breaker] != 0:
        if primes [prime] != 0:
          if (primes[breaker] % primes[prime]) == 0:
            primes[breaker] = 0      
print ("Preparation done.")
print ("Calculating...")
start = datetime.datetime.now()
while (counter < maxval ):
  if counter < maxval:
    counter = counter +1
    thread1 = myThread(1, "Thread-1", counter)
    thread1.start()
  if counter < maxval:
    counter = counter +1
    thread2 = myThread(2, "Thread-2", counter)
    thread2.start()
  if counter < maxval:
    counter = counter +1
    thread3 = myThread(3, "Thread-3", counter)
    thread3.start()
  if counter < maxval:
    counter = counter +1
    thread4 = myThread(4, "Thread-4", counter)
    thread4.start()
  if counter < maxval:
    counter = counter +1
    thread5 = myThread(5, "Thread-5", counter)
    thread5.start()
  thread1.join()
  thread2.join()
  thread3.join()
  thread4.join()
  thread5.join()
#This time.sleep() seems to make the code consistent
  time.sleep(0.05)
  if (counter*100)//maxval > percent:
    percent = (counter*100)//maxval
    print (str(percent) + "%")
end = datetime.datetime.now()
time_needed = end-start
print("\nPrimes to the given max value:")
j = 0
val = 0
while (j <maxval):
  j = j+1
  if primes[j] != 0:
    val = val+1
    if val < 1000000:
      valstr = str(val) + "      "
    if val < 100000:
      valstr = valstr + " "
    if val < 10000:
      valstr = valstr + " "
    if val < 1000:
      valstr = valstr + " "
    if val < 100:
      valstr = valstr + " "
    if val < 10:
      valstr = valstr + " "
    print ( str(valstr) + str(primes[j]))
print ("Time needed for calculation: " + str(time_needed))
print("All primes noted. Script ends.")
```

The error that occurs sometimes is

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "python", line 58, in
>
> RuntimeError: can't start new thread"

if I don't use the Time.Sleep(0.05).
It is not always the same thread and if I use it, I receive no error. As there is a lot of calculations in this script, it would be better without this statement.

Comment: You do know that spawning and joining threads comes with an overhead? Your threads get 5 consecutive numbers from counter, test something and join again , then get assigned the next 5 numbers ... that's more then wasteful - you could _at least_ rule out any %2==0 number. Using threads as you do gives you minus 50 benefit in time and then you are carying around this huge list of 0s ... so memorywise its also not great... Just hunching: try a simple for n in range(...) without threads and your speed should improve significantly.

Comment: Thx for the comment. This is my first Python script so it doesn't have to be the best in my opinion but you are right. Still I am more interested in the answer, why sometimes the thread can't start?